# Using PouchDB-Authentication in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I am trying to use pouchdb-authentication in my Angular 2/TypeScript project.  I performed the following steps:

```
npm install pouchdb-authentication --save
```

This successfully added the directory:

```
node_modules/pouchdb-authentication
```

Next I attempted to import the library into my provider:

```
import * as PouchDBAuthentication from 'pouchdb-authentication';
```

This yielded the error on the 'pouchdb-authentication' portion of this command: "cannot find module: pouchdb-authentication".

Continuing on, I wanted to use the library in the following code in my provider's constructor:

```
this.db.login('username', 'password', function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.name === 'unauthorized') {
      // name or password incorrect
      console.log('name or password incorrect');
    }
    else {
      console.log('some other error logging in');
    }
  }
});
```

This yielded the error: "TypeError: this.db.login is not a function"

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated on how to get pouchdb-authentication working in this project!

Thanks!

Comment: Try out these links, they are not really related to Authentication but still will help http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/ & https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I have actually gotten all of that working just fine.  In fact, I used one of those to help get me to this point.  I actually have the PouchDB/CouchDB part working great, but the data is completely wide open.  Before this can be used for an actual solution I have to integrate authentication, which led me down this path.  PouchDB-authentication is a library that provides the CouchDB authentication logic for PouchDB, but I am not sure how to get that library working within the Angular 2 project.

Comment: @Bob any luck? I'm in the exact same position - got `pouchdb` to work, trying to get `pouchdb-authentication` to work

Comment: Nope, no luck yet.  However, I did see another article about Ionic2 and Cloudant, which is based on CouchDB.  It includes authenticating, so I am going to try that and then see if I can apply that same technique to my own CouchDB instance.  (BTW: This article doesn't utilize couchdb-authentication at all).  I would still like to know the process of getting this to work, as there will be other times in Angular 2 where I need to utilize another JavaScript library like this that cannot be easily Imported.  Hopefully someone chimes in and helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! I've found the way to install any PouchDB plugin to angular2/Ionic2 by installing require typings by following this technique.

If you have not installed typings globally yet :

```
npm install typings --global
```

And

```
typings install dt~require --save --global
```

Then you can initialise any plugin in your angular2/Ionic2 projects like this:

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
```

Now I've got no more internal error from using the signup plugin method :

```
Object {ok: true, id: "org.couchdb.user:robin", rev: "1-434cd15f54ea2ee85042f4e95828cf8c"}
```

Hope it helps !